# Uninitialized value in initializer_list (compiler bug?)

Tags: c++, initialization, clang, valgrind, initializer-list

When the following (reduced) code is compiled with Clang 8.0.0, with `-O1` optimization level (or above), Valgrind detects a `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` error in the resulting binary. No warnings are printed, even with the `-Wall -pedantic` arguments enabled. Adding `-fsanitize=undefined` just makes the issue go away, but doesn't report anything useful.  And it is most likely not a false positive (from Valgrind), since this reduced version originated from a real codebase, where it caused a noticeable error.

When compiled with GCC 9.1.1, there is no UB.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class X {
public:
  int a, b;

  X(int a) : a(a), b(0) {}

  bool h() {
    std::initializer_list<bool> bs({a == 0, a != 0 || b == 0});
    return std::any_of(bs.begin(), bs.end(), [](bool t) { return t; });
  }
};

void f(X g) {
    std::cout << "";
}

int main(int argc, const char **) {
  X i(argc);
  f(i);
  if (i.h())
    std::cout << "";
}
```

Sure, the `std::initializer_list<bool> bs({a == 0, a != 0 || b == 0});` line is a bit weird, and the outer parentheses are unnecessary. But according to [cppinsights.io](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=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&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0), this just adds a copy constructor call, so it should be fine? ([See the same code in Compiler Explorer.](https://godbolt.org/z/NlTLtx))

Also, note that all of the seemingly useless details in the code are necessary to trigger the issue.

So, even if in most cases, the answer to this question is "no": *Is this a bug in Clang?* Or are we just missing something about the quirkiness of modern C++?

Comment: If you remove the parentheses, does the valgrind error go away?

Comment: Yes, it does. Other changes that make it go away: switching `any_of` to `all_of`, removing any of the `std::cout <<` lines, changing the boolean expressions passed into `bs`, or removing the `f(i)` call. It is really elusive. So we could leave it at that, and mark it as "solved", but if we can report an issue to Clang, might as well get to the end of it.

Comment: It looks like a bug or false positive to me.  I wonder if what is going on is `{a == 0, a != 0 || b == 0}` makes an `initializer_list`, then `std::initializer_list<bool> bs(...);` makes a copy, but instead of copying the list, it copies a pointer to the source, which is destroyed at the end of the full expression leaving `bs` with garbage.

Comment: That is entirely possible. Do you have any idea how we could find it out? I'm not familiar with the internals of Clang...

Comment: Checking the assembly could lend some insight.  Unfortunately I'm not great with assembly so I can't really help there.

Comment: And it is most likely not a false positive (from Valgrind), since this reduced version originated from a real codebase, where it caused a noticeable error.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#6 "The array has the same lifetime as any other temporary object ([class.temporary]), except that initializing an initializer_­list object from the array extends the lifetime of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary." Does this count?

Comment: Yeah, I found this clause too, but it only says anything about _extending_ lifetimes, not shortening, and I think even the "usual" lifetime of any object would do here.

Answer (score 1):

I think we ran into an issue that is already reported thrice in the LLVM bug tracker:

- https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22861
- https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40562
- https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42561

And is most likely related to (or might even be the same as) this SO question:

- [Is this unsafe usage of a braced initializer list in a range-based for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43624400/is-this-unsafe-usage-of-a-braced-initializer-list-in-a-range-based-for-loop)

The current standing of the LLVM people on this, is: **"... we ought to issue a warning on this."** Well, yes, I agree.

[Oh, C++...](https://i.imgur.com/3wlxtI0.gifv) :)

Comment: It would help if you explained the issue, rather than referencing external sites.